# Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource comlet is failing with Gateway Timeout! <AzureADPReview module>

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I want to elevate a Azure Resource thru PIM Elevation. And after long search, i found that ... AzureADPreview is the module that helps me do that!

But, I am not able to move forward, as I keep facing this error of Gateway Timeout! when I try the below command!!

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource –ProviderId AzureResources
```

I have ensured trying all below to ensure that I have logged into Azure Account...

Connect-AzAccount
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-pimservice
Connect-MgGraph
Connect-Graph

Also, had set the subscription in context, but NO Luck!

Below are the links I referred...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my method:

1. Run PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Download the AzureADPreview module `Install-module AzureADPreview`.  Please note that you must uninstall all AzureAD modules before downloading the AzureADPreview module `UnInstall-Module AzureAD`, because too many conflicting commands will cause errors.
3. Run the `Connect-AzureAD` command and log in with the Azure AD **global administrator account**.
4. Run the command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for response.

Looks i need Global Administrator account to be able to see the resources. Else it is throwing me Gatway Timeout error.

Comment: @Raja  I forgot this, yes, you must be a global administrator account to see resources, I will add this to the answer to change it to a standard answer. Then, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to end the thread, thank you!